# Slider background doesn't show correctly in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

My slider background shows up in Chrome, Firefox, and most versions of IE, but not in IE8. Its background stays the same color as the rest of the page.

```css
.site-slider {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(images/alexandria/header_overlay.png) no-repeat center top,
                url(images/alexandria/header_bg.jpg);
}
```

If I change `background` to `background-image`, every browser shows the same thing that IE8 does.

[image: The difference]

Answer (score 2):

[IE doesn’t support multiple backgrounds until version 9.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds) You can get around this by adding a wrapper element and applying one background to the parent and one to the child.

```css
.site-slider-wrapper {
    background-image: url(images/alexandria/header_bg.jpg);
}

.site-slider {
    background: url(images/alexandria/header_overlay.png) no-repeat center top;
}
```

The reason changing the property name to `background-image` breaks the CSS in every browser is that the first background sets `background-repeat` and `background-position` properties (`no-repeat center top`) as well, which aren’t valid as part of `background-image`.
 (The whole point of `background` is to be a shorthand for the `background-*` properties.)

Answer (score 0):

You're using a CSS3 "Multiple Backgrounds" feature, which isn't supported in IE8. See its support on [this link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds)

Please read [this tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/curing-css3-headaches-in-older-browsers--webdesign-4469) and find the heading where it says "Multiple Backgrounds". Here you'll find a way to make this property work on IE8 as well.

Secondly, `background` is a shorthand property where you can combine/define values for the following properties:

- `background-color`
- `background-image`
- `background-repeat`
- `background-attachment`
- `background-position`

Eg: `background: #00ff00 url("smiley.gif") no-repeat fixed center;`

On the other hand, if you use any property from the list above, it will accept only values specific to them. They won't work if you'll try to combine any other property value with them. Because of the same reason, your `background-image` property isn't working. You can only define the `url`of the image as a value of `background-image`

Eg: `background-image: url("paper.gif");`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line

```
src /*\**/: url('skins/fonts/titillium/TitilliumText22L003-webfont')\9
```

seemed to fix it...